# Equal Area SRID for Australia

Tags: coordinate-system, australia

Does anyone know the SRID for an equal area projection that is suitable for the whole of Australia?

I realize that I could make my own (which I have done) but I am looking for one that is present already that I can use in both PostgreSQL and Proj4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the [GDA94 / Australian Albers (EPSG:3577)](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3577&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Australian%20EPSG), or the [Australian Albers (EPSG:17365)](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::17365&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Australian%20EPSG).

Comment: EPSG:3577 is exactly what I was after!