# How to calculate areas for data that covers the whole of Australia

Tags: coordinate-system, area, wgs84, australia

I have a polygon shapefile showing mining areas across all of Australia. I want to calculate the area for each of the polygons however they have been provided in a Geographic Coordinate System (GDA_94).

Can anyone tell me what projected coordinate system I could use that would enable me to calculate the areas of each polygon?

Will I need to transform the data and how might this affect the calculations given the size of Australia (i.e. it covers multiple GDA or UTM zones)?

Comment: This question is very similar and might help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/equal-area-srid-for-australia

Answer (score 4):

There are several projected coordinate systems that are valid for the whole Australia. I suggest that you use [Australia Albers equal area](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/australia-albers-equal-area-conic-134/) because global projection often induce more distortions locally. For a global projection suitable for Australia, Hobo-Dyer (a cylindrical equal area projection) could be good too. As you can see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobo%E2%80%93Dyer_projection), the Tissot indicatrice is close to a circle in Australia, which means that there little shape distortion (in addition to being equal-area).

Remark (if you need accurate values): Before you project, make sure that your polygons are delineated with enough vertices (e.g. using some densify function). Indeed **only the vertices are projected** when you change the coordinate system. So if you have large polygon this could cause distortions (vertices are connected by straight lines before and after the projection).

Comment: Thanks very much. To confirm, I can do this in ArcGIS for GDA_94 and WGS_84 (another Aus dataset I have) using the 'Project' tool yes? Will I need to input a Geographic Transformation or is it fine to just chose output coordinate system as GDA 1994 Australia Albers projection? Thanks again

Comment: according to this site (http://www.geoproject.com.au/gda.faq.html), GDA_94 and WGS_84 lie within 1 m. For small scale (in you case whole Australia), there is thus no need for geographic transformations: you can consider that WGS84 and GDA_94 are identical. So you just need to "project" (after "densify")