# Choosing Projected Coordinate System for Western Australia?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, australia

I am using QGIS to observe and analyse spatial distribution of earthquakes in Western Australia. I want to measure polygon areas, and create buffers, for which I need to use a projected coordinate system.

What projected coordinate system should I use for Western Australia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/equal-area-srid-for-australia

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a small area, you can use one of the MGA zones:

[image: MGA Zones of Australia]

The CRS for these is `EPSG:283XX` where XX is one of the numbers.

It sounds like you want to cover all of Western Australia, though, so you probably want to use the [Australian Albers](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/gda94-australian-albers/), which is `EPSG:3577`.